# blender 2.8 texture paint material mode not showing shaded object, just flat color is shown?

Tags: texture-painting

blender 2.8 texture paint material mode not showing shaded object. IT just displays flat color for the object silhoutte. LookDev mode is enabled and it shows the flat color instead of the actual shading of the object with all the respective textures for normal, height etc applied.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the Overlays drop down and turn the Opacity of the Texture all the way down - then you should see the shadows while you paint.
[image]