# Texture Paint window not showing any light

Tags: texturing

I have an object(chair) and light in my scene, everything works fine in object/edit mode. I can switch between display methods and the lights/color change accordingly. But when I click the chair and go into TexturePaint mode, there is no more light/shading. A metallic material will be pure black, an image texture will show all the colors completely flat.

Changing to Lookdev or Rendered Mode doesn't help either. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this, I finally found the same problem asked before with an answer that solved it: [blender 2.8 texture paint material mode not showing shaded object, just flat color is shown?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129596/blender-2-8-texture-paint-material-mode-not-showing-shaded-object-just-flat-col)